# Python. Наследование атрибутов класса и их печать

Tags: python, классы, наследование

Пытаюсь через классы сделать задачу: есть дом, в нем изначально есть 100 рублей. Муж приносит каждый день с работы 150 единиц денег.

```
from termcolor import cprint


class House:
    money = 100

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} Деньги в доме {}'.format(
            self.__class__.__name__, self.money)


class Husband(House):

    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__()
        self.husband_name = name  # имя

    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__()

    def act(self):
        self.work()

    def work(self):
        self.money += 150


home = House()
serge = Husband(name='Сережа')

for day in range(2):
    cprint('================== День {} =================='.format(day), color='red')
    serge.act()
    cprint(serge, color='cyan')
    cprint(home, color='cyan')
```

Проблема в том, что при выводе на экран `cprint(serge, color='cyan')` дает корректный результат - количество денег, накопленное за указанное кол-во дней, а `cprint(home, color='cyan')` - дает изначальные цифры указанные в родительском классе.
Но результат обоих принтов должен быть одинаков.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Но ведь это **разные** объекты, каждый со своим собственным состоянием :)

```
home = House()
serge = Husband(name='Сережа')
```

Это два новых, **разных**, объекта, хотя один и наследник другого. Поэтому и деньги у них врозь.
Вы можете пользоваться и состоянием и функциями родительского объекта, внутри экземпляра класса, и вы это собственно и делаете внутри метода `__str__`! Но если вы создаёте **другой** экземпляр класса - у него будет своё собственное состояние безотносительно того, родитель он, потомок или вообще не родственник другого экземпляра класса.

Чтобы экземпляры класса разделяли общее состояние, нужно пользоваться статическими полями класса, но эти статические поля будут одинаковы вообще у всех экземпляров, а не только у тех, у каких вы захотите.